# Slider on mobile cutting out images WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress plugin installed called Slider and it does not respond to images very well on mobile at all.

I have to enter media queries for the slider to scale down and look mobile responsive, but below a specific size, it starts to cut out the sides of images if they are too big. I've been able to scale the images down for bigger sizes but below 690px it doesn't seem to work without cutting the sides off.

Here is an image of what it looks like on mobile: [image]

If I then increase the width, the images move all the way to the right like below: [image]

So my question is, is there a way to centre the current image?

Here is the only bit of code I think that's holding it in place, but with my width applied:

```
#wds_container1_0 #wds_container2_0 .wds_slideshow_image_0 {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
float: none !important;
padding: 0 !important;
margin: 0 !important;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 500px; }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Master.Deep I've added the specific problem though?